# Browser engine refuses to connect to secure websocket server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, ngrok

### Problem in brief

I get a "Websocket connection failed." error when running this inside of a browser console (Chrome or Brave):

```
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://abcd.ngrok-free.app/")
```

(I'm showing a dummy url here.)

But the same websocket url works fine when testing using wscat:

```
$ wscat -c wss://abcd.ngrok-free.app/
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
< Hello there! This is a websocket server.
```

Why is this happening? There is no detailed error message that shows up in the browser except just `Websocket connection to <wss-url> failed.`

### More Context

The websocket url is an Ngrok url I generated by first running the server on some local host port and then creating an https ngrok url to forward to that port:

1. I run a websocket server on `ws://<some-id-address>:5000`. This address works perfectly fine on my browser. But I need to test my app using a secure websocket server (`wss` instead of `ws`). And to do that...
2. I run `ngrok http 5000` on another terminal. This generates something like `https://abcd.ngrok-free.app/`
3. I then replace the `https` in the ngrok url with `wss`. This alows me to run a secure websocket server on `wss://abcd.ngrok-free.app/`. Again, I have verified that this address works using wscat.

### Help

Just why is the browser javascript unable to connect to the same address that I can interact with using wscat? And how do I fix this? I'm still puzzled. Please help.

I used `ws` instead of `wss` in the ngrok url. That didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Short version**: I don't think ngrok's free tier supports WebSocket connections when initiated from a browser.

**Long version**: I ran into the same problem and in my case the issue appeared to be related to ngrok's free tier's "browser warning" page.

In my browser, I copied the failing WebSocket connection request in CURL format and ran it on the command line. The response I received was *HTML* (instead of anything WebSocket protocol-related), with text like:

> You are about to visit <something>.ngrok-free.app, served by <some IP address>. This website is served for free through ngrok.com. You should only visit this website if you trust whoever sent the link to you.

If I modify the "User-Agent" header on the CURL command line, then it seems to connect to the WebSocket just fine. So it appears that ngrok is looking for browser requests and then injecting a warning page, even though the request is an upgrade request for WebSockets.